# Select MAX with PHP/SQL Server with ADODB

Tags: php, sql-server, max, adodb

I need to select the maximum value from a table , as described below , but do not return anything. I use PHP / SQL Server with library ADODB.

```
<?php
session_start();
//connessione al DB
include("dati_db.inc.php");
include ("init.php");
$qry = "select (IDSQL) from test.dbo.TTS_ext_ticket";
echo $qry;
$newrecordSet = $db->Execute($qry);
if ($db->ErrorMsg() != '') {    echo $db->ErrorMsg().' '.$condition; return;}

$ID_TICKET=$recordSet->fields["idticket"];
echo $ID_TICKET;   
?>
```

Comment: You need MAX for MAX: `MAX(IDSQL)` and an alias too

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Selecting a Record With MAX Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387587/sql-server-selecting-a-record-with-max-value)

Answer (score 1):

Use [MAX](http://sql.sh/fonctions/agregation/max)() Like :

```
$qry = "select MAX(IDSQL) AS max_idsql from test.dbo.TTS_ext_ticket";
```

Comment: in truth I had already changed the query , but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
$qry = "select MAX(IDSQL) AS idticket from test.dbo.TTS_ext_ticket";
```

**Note that** the alias is named as `idticket` as this is what you expect later in code.