# I have a set of data and need to return the corresponding row on the select max(date)

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of data and trying to get the max date and the data that correspond to the selected `max(date)`.

This is my sample table

```
ch_no       ch_stat  d_issue
10461536    UB       2018-04-06 00:00:00.000
10462330    UB       2018-05-04 00:00:00.000
10575171    UB       2018-06-05 00:00:00.000
10593518    UB       2018-07-09 00:00:00.000
10613044    UB       2018-08-02 00:00:00.000
10641949    UB       2018-09-04 00:00:00.000
10643136    UB       2018-10-09 00:00:00.000
10670638    UB       2018-11-05 00:00:00.000
```

Query

```
select max(d_issue),max(ch_no)from carlos.claims_checks
```

I want to return result like to be

```
d_issue     ch_no
2018-11-05  10670638
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a Record With MAX Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387587/selecting-a-record-with-max-value)

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposal query

```
DECLARE @MyDataset AS TABLE
(
  ch_no INT ,
  ch_stat  CHAR(10),
  d_issue DATETIME2 
)

INSERT INTO @MyDataset (   ch_no ,
                           ch_stat ,
                           d_issue
                       )
VALUES (   10461536 ,             -- ch_no - int
           'UB' , -- ch_stat - datetime2
           '2018-04-06 00:00:00.000'               -- d_issue - int
       ),
(   10462330 ,             -- ch_no - int
           'UB' , -- ch_stat - datetime2
           '2018-05-04 00:00:00.000'               -- d_issue - int
       ),
       (   10575171 ,             -- ch_no - int
           'UB' , -- ch_stat - datetime2
           '2018-06-05 00:00:00.000'               -- d_issue - int
       ),
       (   10593518 ,             -- ch_no - int
           'UB' , -- ch_stat - datetime2
           '2018-07-09 00:00:00.000'               -- d_issue - int
       ),
       (   10641949 ,             -- ch_no - int
           'UB' , -- ch_stat - datetime2
           '2018-09-04 00:00:00.000'               -- d_issue - int
       ),
       (   10670638 ,             -- ch_no - int
           'UB' , -- ch_stat - datetime2
           '2018-11-05 00:00:00.000'               -- d_issue - int
       );

WITH MyCTE AS
(
SELECT MAX(d_issue) AS selected_date
FROM @MyDataset
),
MYCTE_chno AS
(
SELECT TOP 1 ch_no,MCT.selected_date
FROM @MyDataset AS MDS
INNER JOIN MyCTE MCT
ON MDS.d_issue=MCT.selected_date
)
SELECT * FROM MYCTE_chno
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest query would be this

```
SELECT cc.d_issue,cc.ch_no
FROM carlos.claims_checks cc
WHERE cc.d_issue = (SELECT MAX(d_issue) FROM carlos.claims_checks)
```

If you just want the max date for each ch_no do this :

```
SELECT MAX(d_issue), ch_no FROM carlos.claims_checks GROUP BY ch_no
```