# Select row with max value in multiple where condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I edited the following query based on this page:

[Selecting a Record With MAX Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387587/selecting-a-record-with-max-value)

Select query :

```
select 
    Users.Id, Users.[Name], Users.Family, Users.BirthDate,
    Users.Mobile, Users.[Description], Users.Email,
    Users.UserName, Users.fatherName,
    Users.archiveNumber, Users.[Address], Users.IsMarried,
    Users.Mazhab, 
    Cities.CityName, Religions.PersianName, Users.Date_insert, 
    Users.ImageName,
    MaghtaeTahsilis.[Name] as MaghtaeTahsilisName,
    FieldStudies.[Name] as FieldStudiesName,
    Eductionals.Institute, Eductionals.Moaddal, 
    Eductionals.FromYear, Eductionals.ToYear
from 
    Users 
left outer join 
    Eductionals on Users.id = Eductionals.UserID
left outer join 
    MaghtaeTahsilis on Eductionals.MaghtaeID = MaghtaeTahsilis.ID
left outer join 
    Cities on Users.City_Id = Cities.Id
left outer join 
    Religions on Users.Relegion_ID = Religions.ID
left outer join 
    FieldStudies on Eductionals.FieldStudy_ID = FieldStudies.ID
where 
    Users.UserName = @code_melli 
    and Eductionals.MaghtaeID = (select MAX(MaghtaeID) from Eductionals 
                                 where Eductionals.UserID = Users.Id)
```

This command works correctly in choosing `MAX` value, But if the following statement has a `NULL` value, no row are returned. I want to show `NULL` value if it is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `left outer join`s are being turned into `inner join`s by the `where` conditions.  Your query should look like:

```
select u.Id, u.[Name], u.Family, u.BirthDate, u.Mobile, u.[Description], u.Email, u.UserName, u.fatherName,
       u.archiveNumber, u.[Address], u.IsMarried, u.Mazhab, c.CityName, r.PersianName, u.Date_insert, u.ImageName,
       mt.[Name] As MaghtaeTahsilisName, fs.[Name] As FieldStudiesName, e.Institute, e.Moaddal, e.FromYear, e.ToYear
from Users u left outer join
     Eductionals e
     on u.id = e.UserID and
        e.MaghtaeID = (select MAX(e2.MaghtaeID)
                       from Eductionals e2
                       where e2.UserID = u.Id
                      ) left outer join
     MaghtaeTahsilis mt
     on e.MaghtaeID = mt.ID left outer join
     Cities c
     on u.City_Id = c.Id left outer join
     Religions r
     on u.Relegion_ID = r.ID left outer join
     FieldStudies fs
     on e.FieldStudy_ID = fs.ID
where u.UserName = @code_melli ;
```

Conditions on the first table -- in a chain of `left join`s should be in the `where` clause.  On subsequent tables in the `on` clauses.

You'll notice that I also added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

You can also use window functions:

```
from Users u left outer join
     (select e2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by e2.userId order by e2.MaghtaeID desc) as seqnum
      from Eductionals e2
     ) e
     on u.id = e.UserID and
        e.seqnum = 1 left outer join
     . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for returning zero records when second query returns `NULL` is, when second query returns NULL, your SQL syntax become like this

```
And Eductionals.MaghtaeID=NULL
```

And probably Dbtable `Educationals` holds NULL values for field `MaghtaeID`.
So SQL fails above syntax and thus returns zero records. 
Correct syntax for checking NULL values would be

```
And Eductionals.MaghtaeID is NULL
```

So please modify where condition in your query as follows which will return desired result.

```
where Users.UserName = @code_melli AND isnull(Eductionals.MaghtaeID,0) = isnull((select MAX(MaghtaeID) from Eductionals where Eductionals.UserID = Users.Id),0)
```