# SQL select all columns to return only with MAX seqno

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Below query returns multiple rows as you can see in the image below.

I want to know how to return only one row with MAX seqno on it. Also note that I want to return all columns from the table here.

Appreciate you help.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR HD 
JOIN dbo.SALESORDHIST AS HI ON HD.SEQNO = HI.HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ
                            AND hi.FILEURL <> '' 
                            AND HI.EVENT_TYPE='D'
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to return just `SEQNO` column or all the columns?

Comment: I want to return all columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a Record With MAX Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387587/selecting-a-record-with-max-value)

Comment: I read that question but can not find instance where it can be applied to return all columns with join in the query

Answer (score 5):

How about ordering the records and selecting only the first one?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR HD 
JOIN dbo.SALESORDHIST AS HI ON HD.SEQNO = HI.HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ
                            AND hi.FILEURL <> '' 
                            AND HI.EVENT_TYPE='D'
ORDER BY HD.SEQNO DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
select * 
FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR HD 
JOIN dbo.SALESORDHIST AS HI 
   ON HD.SEQNO = HI.HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ and hi.FILEURL <> '' AND HI.EVENT_TYPE='D'
WHERE HD.SEQNO = (
  SELECT MAX(HD.SEQNO) FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR HD 
JOIN dbo.SALESORDHIST AS HI 
   ON HD.SEQNO = HI.HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ AND hi.FILEURL <> '' AND HI.EVENT_TYPE='D'
)
```

Comment: this still returns multiple columns.

Comment: does HD.SEQNO unique? without knowing your table structure it is hard to understand what you need. check my edited answer again please

Comment: then joined table must have multiple rows

Comment: used inner join instead of join and it worked. Thanks for the guidance.