# Select Max number with another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am writing a simple query to get the VENDOR_ID that has the MAX ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM so that I would have the following output:

```
VENDOR_ID     ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
76109A        81
```

The problem is when I write the following SQL I am getting back every VENDOR_ID and it's own max ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM, whereas I want just the VENDOR_ID and max ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM in the entire table.

```
SELECT VENDOR_ID, MAX(ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM)
FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL
GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387587/selecting-a-record-with-max-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a Record With MAX Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387587/selecting-a-record-with-max-value)

Answer (score 5):

`ORDER BY` ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM descending. Use `TOP 1` to get the first row only, i.e. the row having the highest ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM value.

```
SELECT TOP 1 VENDOR_ID, ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL
ORDER BY ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM DESC;
```

Comment: awesome! so Max function isn't needed? Is it possible to write it using Max function and still get both columns and just the max row?

Comment: @JBinson88 yes, you can do that as well, but if you only need to get one vendor_id, then jaralh approach is your best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a subselect

`SELECT VENDOR_ID, ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM
FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL
WHERE ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM = (SELECT MAX(ADDRESS_SEQ_NUM)
                         FROM PS_VNDR_ADDR_SCROL)`